# ７色 vs 七色 for rainbow (7 colors vs 7 prismatic colors)

Tags: pronunciation, numbers

> 虹は7色だ。
>   Rainbow has 7 colors.
>   There are 7 colors in rainbow.

Question:
how to pronounce 7色 to make meaning [7 colors]?

Problem:
七色 is not [7 colors].
It is a special scientific term, meaning [7-prismatic-colors].
We do not make [7 colors] meaning, if we pronounce this sentence like this.

> 虹は七色だ。
>   [niji-wa nana-iro da]
>   Rainbow is the seven prismatic colors (thing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The counter for color is 色（**しょく**）. If you want to say "seven (different) colors" without any idiomatic meaning, you can say ななしょく.

> 地図を[7色]{ななしょく}に塗り分ける
>   to paint a map using seven different colors

When you say like this, the colors can be anything including gray, brown and pink. Alternatively, you can just say 7つの色【いろ】.

---

The word [七色【なないろ】](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%B8%83%E8%89%B2_%28%E3%81%AA%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%82%8D%29/), in kanji, specifically refers to the seven colors of a rainbow. (I wouldn't call this a scientific term...) It also means "a wide variety of", as in 七色の声.